# JavaFX managing polling threads tied to scene lifecycle

Tags: multithreading, javafx

In the following example there is an FXML controller running a separate thread to update components periodically.

If the users clicks to navigate away from this controller and comes back to this controller, there will be 2 threads running in the background. (The first one never stopped).

How can I ensure that there is only ever 1 thread and that this thread is tied to the life of the controller ?

```
<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
            fx:controller="example.BorderController"
            fx:id="rootPane">
    <left>
        <VBox>
        <Button text="Pane1" onAction"#goToPane1"/>
        <Button text=Pane2" onAction="goToPane2"/>
        </VBox>
    </left>
</BorderPane>
```

.

```
public class BorderController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private BorderPane rootPane;

    @FXML
    public void goToPane1(ActionEvent event) {
        showPage("fxml/Pane1");
    }

    @FXML
    public void goToPane2(ActionEvent event) {
        showPage("fxml/Pane2");
    }

    private void showPage(final Stringpage) {
        try {
            rootPane.setCenter((Node) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(page)));

        } catch (final IOException ex) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "An error occurred loading the page.", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
public class Pane1Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML private Label toUpdate;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
                final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                System.out.println("Pane1 " + this);
                toUpdate.setText(Instant.now().toString());
            });
        }, 2, 2, SECONDS);
    }
}
```

After navigating between the 2 panes the output is as follows:

```
Pane1 example.Pane1@45892b4c
Pane1 example.Pane1@6dc7392e
Pane1 example.Pane1@45892b4c
Pane1 example.Pane1@6dc7392e
// Repeats
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can observe the `sceneProperty()` of a node in the pane, and start or shutdown the `ScheduledExecutor` accordingly:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class Pane1Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label toUpdate;

    @FXML
    private Pane root;

    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        root.sceneProperty().addListener((obs, oldScene, newScene) -> {
            if (newScene == null && scheduler != null) {
                scheduler.shutdown();
            }
            if (newScene != null) {

                scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1, runnable -> {
                    Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
                    t.setDaemon(true);
                    return t ;
                });

                scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
                    Platform.runLater(() -> {
                        System.out.println("Pane1 " + this);
                        toUpdate.setText(Instant.now().toString());
                    });
                } , 2, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Any node in the pane will generally work, though it probably makes most sense to use the pane itself (which I gave `fx:id="root"` here). Note I also made the thread used by the executor a daemon thread, so it will not prevent the application exiting.

Finally, note that for the functionality you used in the example (in which everything in the scheduled task is performed on the FX Application Thread), the Animation API might be cleaner than the `java.util.concurrent` API, though your real application may require the latter:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Pane1Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label toUpdate;

    @FXML
    private Pane root;

    private Timeline timeline ;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), e-> {
            System.out.println("Pane1 " + this);
            toUpdate.setText(Instant.now().toString());         
        }));
        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);

        root.sceneProperty().addListener((obs, oldScene, newScene) -> {
            if (newScene == null) {
                timeline.pause();
            } else {
                timeline.play();
            }
        });

    }
}
```